# Setting pipefail for a single piped command

Tags: linux, command-line, shell, pipe

I need to execute a number of piped shell commands from a non-BASH script (namely PHP script) like these:

```
command1 | command2 | command3
```

so that, if `command1` fails with a non-zero exit code, each other command fails too. So far, what I've come up with is:

```
set -o pipefail && command1 | command2 | command3
```

But even though it runs fine from the terminal, it produces this if executed from the script:

> sh: 1: set: Illegal option -o pipefail

Comment: It appears that `/bin/sh` doesn't like `set -o pipefail`.  Is it actually `bash` in disguise, or is it a different shell?  When `bash` is run as `/bin/sh`, does it accept `set -o pipefail`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler When I run `/bin/sh set -o pipefail` it says `/bin/sh: 0: Can't open set` (same thing with `sudo`). Hope I tested it right. The system is Ubuntu 12.

Comment: You'd need to try `/bin/sh -c "set -o pipefail"`; as it was, the shell was trying to execute a script in the current directory called `set` and it didn't find it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `/bin/sh -c "set -o pipefail"` isn't working, however `bash -c "set -o pipefail"` does.

Comment: So, your problem is that the script is run by `/bin/sh` which doesn't recognize `set -o pipefail`.  Consequently, you'll need to ensure that the script is run by `/bin/bash` instead of `/bin/sh`. Or, if you're confident, brave — and probably foolhardy — change `/bin/sh` to be a link to, or copy of, `/bin/bash` instead of whichever shell it currently is linked to or a copy of.  If you're sure that `/bin/sh` is `bash`, then you're using behaviour which `bash` doesn't expose when run as `/bin/sh`; use `bash` as `bash`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, thanks a lot. A strange thing by the way is that PHP reports it's using `/bin/bash` when I ask PHP about it with `echo $_SERVER["SHELL"];`..

Comment: The `pipefail` option is a `bash` addition. `/bin/sh` in ubuntu is not bash by default. The solution is to begin the script with `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh` if you want to run bash instead.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From the Bash command line you would need to invoke a subshell to avoid `pipefail` being set afterwards:

```
$ (set -o pipefail && command1 | command2 | command3)
```

This would limit the effect of the `pipefail` option to the subshell create by the parentheses `(...)`.

A real example:

```
$ (set -o pipefail && false | true) && echo pipefail inactive || echo pipefail active
pipefail active
```

If you use an explicit shell call with the `-c` option you do not need a subshell, either with `bash` or with an `sh` alias to `bash`:

```
$ bash -c "set -o pipefail && false | true" && echo pipefail inactive || echo pipefail active
pipefail active
$ sh -c "set -o pipefail && false | true" && echo pipefail inactive || echo pipefail active
pipefail active
```

Since your `sh` does not accept the `pipefail` option, I would have to assume that it is either some older or modified version of `bash` - or that it is actually some other shell completely.

Comment: Is `$` in the first piece a part of the command is it just a shell prompt? Tried both ways, didn't really work. The `bash -c` way always works, not too elegant tho..

Comment: Also, if you are invoking a `bash -c "..."` you may as well just set the options on bash instead of calling set in your bash.. `bash -o pipefail -c "myCommand"`

Answer (score 12):

Not sure why it wasn't mentioned above, but it is possible to explicitly unset `pipefail`, using `set +o pipefail`.

```
set -o pipefail
command1 | command2 | command3
set +o pipefail
```

If you are executing a fragment, and unsure about the `pipefail` already set, you can use this with the subshell as previously suggested:

```
# explicitly execute with pipefail set
(set -o pipefail ; command1 | command2 | command3 )
# explicitly execute with pipefail unset
(set +o pipefail ; command1 | command2 | command3 )
```

Comment: you are a gentleperson and a scholar

Answer (score -1):

You can use $(command1) combined with $? :

```
a=$(echo "a")
[ $? -eq 0 ] && b=$(echo $a"b")
[ $? -eq 0 ] && c=$(echo $b"c")
echo $c
```

Prints "abc"

```
a=$(ls unexitingDir)
[ $? -eq 0 ] && b=$(echo $a"b")
[ $? -eq 0 ] && c=$(echo $b"c")
echo $c
```

Prints "".

"[ $? -eq 0 ] &&" means that the following command is executed only if the previous one succed.

That dosen't answer your question but it's a solution to your problem.

Comment: Does it mean that I would always need to store the output of each of the commands into a variable?

Comment: Always I don't know but with my solution yes you will (if you need it for your next command). Unless you can just write `command1 && command2 && command3`